# Choose different viewmodels based on object property

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I need to show different usercontrols as detailed view for my viewmodels
Assume I have list of my viewModels

```
class BuildingVM
{
    String Name {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

i need to show "Name = Market" - > "TradeControl", "Name = Academy" -> "ScienceControl" etc inside my content control

view:

```
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="240"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView  
           Grid.Column=0              
            Background="Transparent" 
            Name="BuildingsList" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Buildings}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lvBuildingListItem}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedBuilding}"
            />
    </DockPanel>

    <ContentControl 
       Grid.Column="1" 
       Content="{Binding Path=SelectedBuilding}"/>

</Grid>
```

It is *not* about using different templates to visualize BuildingVM for different values of name property, its about mapping to other controls with their own viewmodels and datacontexts

Comment: Is the list of controls a fixed list or is it something where you could register new controls?

Comment: It should be predefined i suppose.

Comment: hi andrey - have a look at my suggestion. if this is not what you are looking for we can have a chat and sort it out if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok then except if there is something I have missed I think you should use the `DataTemplateSelector`. This selector will return one `DataTemplate` (containing the usercontrol you want) for each cases you want to handle with the Name property. You will find all info about the `DataTemplateSelector` here or on the web but if there is something you don't get, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are going the right way with this already. All that's missing is an entry in your App.xaml like this:

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type thetypeofyourviewmodel}">
    <Typeofcontrolyouwanttouseforrendering />
</DataTemplate>
```

Doing it this way combined with a ContentPresenter (You're using ContentControl) is the common way to dynamically render content.